# Build errors when attempting to use boost::asio for the first time

Tags: boost, boost-asio

I use many parts of boost in other projects. I want to experiment with boost asio, but I am failing at the first step. Given the minimal code . .

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp> 

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

and compiling on a mac with

> clear; g++ client.cpp -I/path_to_boost/ -o clientapp

I get the error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
>         __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccLQRfXY.o
>         boost::asio::error::get_system_category()    in ccLQRfXY.o
>         boost::system::error_code::error_code()in ccLQRfXY.o   "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
>         __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccLQRfXY.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: ld returned
>   1 exit status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.Asio depends on Boost.System, so you should also link libboost_system.